# Getting "Login failed for user 'TestUser'." during the connection to DB via ASP.Net Program

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect my DB via a program in ASP.Net but I get below error:

> Login failed for user 'TestUser'.

It is important to notice that I am able to connect by MySQL Workbench to this database remotely and successfully. Also in Visual Studio, I am able to connect to this database via Tools>Connect to Database. I am using the same connection string that is successful for the above mentioned operation. But once I try to use Connection method with the same connection string in the program, I face with "Login failed for user 'TestUser'." error.

The Web.config file used here is as below:

```
<add name="EmployeeConnString" connectionString="server=164.138.16.111;user id=TestUser;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=Employee"/>
```

This is the piece of the code I am using:

```
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeConnString"].ConnectionString;

            connection = new SqlConnection(conn);

            if (connection.State.ToString()=="Closed")
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    lblResult.Text = connection.State.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblResult.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
```

[Successful Connection via Visual Studio>Tools>Connect to Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rfUO.png)
[The view of the database in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBjOw.png)

How can I fix this problem and make a successful Connect command?

Comment: Your connection string does not have a password in it. Maybe that is the problem? Are you entering a password when you connect through Visual Studio or MySql Workbench?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Dear Jordan Wilcken,

As mentioned this string is exactly the one which is successful for Tools>Connect to Database.

I have also tried it with password but I receive the same Error. 
I have used below strings and they have had same problem:

<add name="EmployeeConnString" connectionString="server=164.138.16.111;user id=TestUser;password=#ndi%0EcjAmH1AuD;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=Employee"/>




<add name="EmployeeConnString" connectionString="server=164.138.16.111;user id=TestUser;password=#ndi%0EcjAmH1AuD;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=Employee"/>

Answer (score 0):

I used wireshark to spot the problem. It seems that I must specify the port (3306), otherwise it communicates with wrong port.
However, still I have problem, no I receive below error:

"Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18".

Below image shows the wireshark log for problematic log in via program. It seems that something causes that packets be transmitted out of order!

Here is the log for the problematic log in via program:
[Problematic log in wireshark log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfTul.png)

Following is the wireshark log for successful log in via Tools>Connect to Database:
[successful log in wire shark log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdYvO.png)

Here is the Description of Error shown in wireshark for programmatic log in:
[Error shown in wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7xf8.png)

However still I do not know how to fix it. Any suggestion on how to fix it?